# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {job}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, async-await, axios

Using axios to fetch data from an api and then trying to map the values and display them in a different component.

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import JobBoardComponent from './components/JobBoardComponent';
import axios from 'axios';

function App(): JSX.Element {

  const[jobs, setJobs] = useState<any>([]); 

  useEffect((): void => {
     const fetchJobs = async () => {
        const res = await axios('http://localhost:5000/jobs');
        setJobs(res.data);
     };
     fetchJobs();
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
     {jobs.map((job: any) => <JobBoardComponent job={job} key={job.id} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

JobBoardComponent.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

function JobBoardComponent( job: any, key: any){
    return (
        <div>
           <h1>{ job }</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default JobBoardComponent;
```

It looks like the API is working.

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZQ8m08cbF0 but I decided to make my own API and now it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the structure of the stateful `jobs` variable?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by stateful jobs structure but if you mean the steucture of the json data then the structure is like this ....{
    "id": 1,
    "company": "Photosnap",
    "logo": "./images/photosnap.svg",
    "new": true,
    "featured": true,
    "position": "Senior Frontend Developer",
    "role": "Frontend",
    "level": "Senior",
    "postedAt": "1d ago",
    "contract": "Full Time",
    "location": "USA Only",
    "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
    "tools": []
  },

Comment: you are not passing props correctly, JobBoardComponent( {job: any, key: any})

Answer (score 2):

Please, do not use `any` [unless you are in the process of migrating a js project to ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any) (or you **REALLY** don't care what type the variable will be, even then you still should consider using [unknown](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#unknown) type instead.)

As for your problem, if I were you, for the quick and dirty way of displaying the "unknown" data I would do something like this (or just `console.log` it if data is too large):

```
    ...
    <h1>{ JSON.stringify(job) }</h1>
    ...
```

And I am guessing, from the error you just mentioned (and from the above script that will justify my guess if you include it), `job` is a nested [object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object), which is not valid data for displaying in React. Probably you should destructure your `job` variable inside `JobBoardComponent`.

Again, you can **avoid these kind of errors** if you give your `job` variable a non-`any` type, linter will warn you if you are assigning wrong types, which you can't when using `any`.